# What is an alternative to using DOM XML parser for large XML Documents for multiple find operations?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, memory

I am storing data for ranking users in XML documents - one row per user - containing a 36 char key, score, rank, and username as attributes.

`<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>`
`<!DOCTYPE Ranks [<!ELEMENT Rank ANY ><!ATTLIST Rank id ID #IMPLIED>]>`
`<Ranks>`
`..<Rank id="<userKey>" score="36.0" name="John Doe" rank=15></Rank>..`
`</Ranks>`

There are several such documents which are parsed on request using a DOM parser and kept in memory until the file is updated. This happens from within a HttpServlet which is backing a widget. Every time the widget is loaded it calls the servlet with a get request which then requires one of the documents to be queried. The queries on the documents require the following operations:

- Look up - finding a particular ID
- Iterate through each Rank element and get the id attribute

In my test environment the number of users is <100 and everything works well. However we are soon supposed to be delivering to a system with 200K+ users. I have serious concerns about the scalability of my approach - i.e. OutOfMemoryException!

I'm stuck for ideas for an implementation which balances performance and memory usage. While DOM is good for find operations it may choke because of the large size. I don't know much about StAX, but from what I have read it seems that it might solve the memory issue but could really slow down the queries as I will have to effectively iterate through the document to find the element of interest (Is that correct?).

Questions:

- Is it possible to use StAX for multiple find (like getElementById) operations on large documents quick enough to serve an HttpRequest?
- What is the maximum file size that a DOM Parser can handle?
- Is it possible to estimate how much memory per user would be used for an XML document with the above structure?

Thanks

Edit: I am not allowed to use databases.

Edit: Would it be better/neater to use a custom formatted file instead and use Regular expressions to search the file for the required entry?

Comment: [This project](http://xmltk.sourceforge.net/) might be of interest.  I read about it a while ago but never tried it out myself.  (I ended up writing my own specialized XML stream processor for .NET.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're using the xml document as a database. I think you'll be much happier using a proper database for this, and importing/exporting to xml as needed. Several databases work well, so you might as well use one that's well supported, like mysql or postgresql, although even sqlite will work better than xml.

In terms of SAX parsing, you basically build a large state machine that handles various events that occur while parsing (entering a tag, leaving a tag, seeing data, etc.). You're then on your own to manage memory (recording the data you see depending on the state you're in), so you're correct that it can have a better memory footprint, but running a query like that for every web request is ridiculous, especially when you can store all your data in a nice indexed database.

Comment: I agree, a proper database would be awesome - but as one of our contraints we are only allowed to use one table in the database (with a predetermined structure). SO effectively not allowed to use databases.

Comment: That seems like stupid constraint.  But, if you can't use "the" database, it is easy enough to build your own in memory.  Your "records" aren't very complicated; a simple struct will store them just fine (although you might share the strings if there's any chance they are identical).  Building a hash table or other index on top of array of these is pretty easy. Read the XML, build your data base in memory.  I would guess your struct would be a few tens of bytes, times 200K --> 4M bytes, times several documents --> 12M bytes.   What's the problem?

Comment: I'm sure there's some pedagogical value in that constraint, although it sounds fishy to me :/ You can still probably use that table to store your data, although it'll mean jumping through some hoops. An sqlite database is just a file on the filesystem, so you should still check that out. Alternatively, if you want to store everything in memory, consider optimizing your memory usage by only storing what's absolutely necessary in arrays and hash tables, and then serializing to/from xml as needed.

Comment: @Ira Baxter : Well isn't the DOM Document object effectively a Database in memory? If the DTD specifies what the ID attribute is then the Document contains an underlying hashset which makes the lookups of O(1) complexity. There might be around 60 of these documents in memory at a given time. I would imagine that 240 MB used by one thread would affect the performance of the entire server yes? 
SO the problem mainly is whether to hold all information in memory or find a way to get to it quickly on disk.

Comment: @JayAgrawal It is a sort of in-memory data structure, although it's not necessarily optimized for finding elements, and it's usually extremely bloated. For example, xmlbeans is a great library, which allows you to search through the document using XPath queries, transform it using XSLT, and several other advanced operations. But you don't need any of this functionality, so you end up with heavyweight objects that take up memory.

Comment: @JayAgrawal: Yes, the DOM is an in memory database.  Who says it is efficient for his particular kind of data?  My answer suggests his data is tiny if he makes any attempt to store it efficiently, by most memory standards today, so what's the worry?

Comment: @JayAgrawal: If you build a space-tight database in your *virtual* memory address space, the part you don't use will go the disk. If you implement hash tables with O(1) lookup time, you'll need O(1) disk reads to get your table entry.  If you don't mind 30 milliseconds per random lookup, this should be fine.  If you do lots of these, the VM part of your OS is supposed to decide that data is in your working set, and hold it in memory.  And 240MB is still peanuts on a server.

Comment: Hmm..So basically I should trim the data, as in store only what is necessary; and not use XML. Instead I should read the entire file and build Hashmaps and arrays to store the data in memory for lookup and iterate operations.
The only problem now is the amount of time taken to read a file and convert string data to the said data structures. Hopefully we will get a decent test environment to run some stress tests soon. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: @JayAgrawal: It shouldn't take your code any longer to read the XML documents, than it would take a DOM reader. You should be pretty much disk bound.

Answer (score 2):

One of the big problems here is that DOM is not thread-safe, so even read operations need to be synchronized. From that point of view, using JDOM or XOM would definitely be better.

The other issue is the search strategy used to find the data. You really want the queries to be supported by indexing rather than using serial search. In fact, you need a decent query optimizer to generate efficient access paths. So given your constraint of not using a database, this sounds like a case for an in-memory XQuery engine with agressive optimization, for which the obvious candidate is Saxon-EE. But then I would say that, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 0):

For heavy due XML processing, VTD-XML is the most efficient option available, it is far more efficent than JDOM, DOM4j or DOM... the key is non-object oriented approach of its info-set modeling... it is also far less likely to cause out of memory exception... Read this 2013 paper for the comprehensive comparison/benchmark between various XML frameworks

[Processing XML with Java – A Performance Benchmark](http://sdiwc.us/digitlib/journal_paper.php?paper=00000582.pdf)